# regular expression to compare variables inside html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

Ive been going through the regular expression things and consider we have an array which has html tags stored in as strings..
like `array=["</div>,"</a>", "<div id='test'>", "<a href='http://test/new.html'>", "</a>", "</div>", "<span style='color:#ffffff;'>"]`

if we go through the array one by one,

if we want to detect complete tags and incomplete tags, like for example,`<div>` is openened and `</div>` its closed in location after that.. so those two comes under complete tags... `<span>` is opened, but never closed, so it comes under incomplete open tags, `</div>` at first location is closed, so it comes under incomplete closed tags.

Can this be done using JavaScript?

Comment: You just want to match open items with closed items? Perfectly reasonable in Javascript. Has nothing to do with regular expressions (if i'm understanding the question correctly)

Comment: yes @ngmiceli.. in the order they come inside array

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a great problem for teaching the utilities of the Stack data type. In Javascript, all arrays have use of stack functions, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods).

How do you do it?

Start with an empty stack.
Loop through the elements of your array, in order. For each item:

- If it is an open tag, push it on to your stack.
- If it is a close tag, pop the top item from your stack

  - Check that the two tags match. (You must close the most recently opened item, no?)
  - If not, fail

Finally, when you've finished your array, check that the stack is empty.

- If not, not every tag was closed. Fail
- If so, success!

For example:

```
[<div>, <a>, <span>, </span>, </div>, </a>]
```

Will fail. Push `div`, push `a`, push `span`. Pop `span`. Pop `a`, which does not match `div`

It should look like

```
[<div>, <a>, <span>, </span>, </a>, </div>]
```

Which will pass, as the stack will be empty (have a length of 0) at the end of the method.

---

**Edit: If you want to use regex in the separate steps:**

*To determine if a tag is open:*

```
tag.match(/<\//) == null
```

This checks if a tag contains the characters `<\`

*To get the content from a tag:*

```
var tagContent = tag.match(/\w+/)[0];
```

This grabs a group of word characters. Specifically, the first group. It should just grab the tag name and ignore any attributes, as the whitespace will end the expression. Match always returns an array, in case you matched globally (where there would be multiple matches), so get the 0-th index of the returned array to get the value.

*To compare two tags:*

```
tag1Content == tag2Content
```

This seriously does not require regex.

Comment: but to compare the tags, we will have to use regular expressions right?

Comment: Not necessarily! Regular expressions get their power from pattern matching, of which you're doing fairly little in this situation. You *can* use them, but you do not *have* to. All you need is a means to determine if a tag is open or closed, and get the text out. From there, it's as simple as string comparison in the "check that the two tags match" step, which can be done with the `equals` method. You can do all of this with regex, or by "hand".

Comment: but consider the instance <a href= 'http://this.test.html' />will try this one out..

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer as well. The simple regular expression provided at the bottom should get the tag name and ignore any attributes.

Comment: @SamDaSilva I'm not sure what you're expecting, but it works. `var test = "<a href='test/new.html'; />"; var tagname = test.match(/\w+/);` tagname has a value of `['a']`, as it should. `tagname[0]` is `'a'`. What else would you want? It doesn't matter what the `href` is, all you want to know is you opened an `a` or you closed an `a`.

Comment: i meant <a href="whatver it is" /> is a closed tag... right??

Comment: Ive posted my answer...check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stack=new Array();
var stackCount = 0;

 var array=["</div>","<div id='test'>", "<a href='http://test/new.html'>", "</a>", "</div>", "<span style='color:#ffffff;'>"];    
        for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++)
        {
                    alert("Eleemnt Selected:" + array[k]);
                    if(stackCount==0)
                        {
                        if(array[k].match(/<\//)==null)
                            {
                            stack.push(array[k]);
                            stackCount++;
                            alert("Pushed in to the stack as stack is empty" + stack);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            alert("Ignored as it is a tag containing slash");
                            }

                        }
                    else
                        {
                        var tagType1=array[k].match(/<\//);
                        var tagType2=stack[0].match(/<\//);
                        var cmpTag1=array[k].match(/\w+/);  
                        var cmpTag2=stack[0].match(/\w+/);

                        //alert("Tag Type : Array element :" +tagType1 + "Stack element : " +  tagType2 + "Tag Name: Array element : " + cmpTag1 + "Stack Element : " +cmpTag2);
                        if(cmpTag1!=cmpTag2 && tagType1!=tagType2)
                            {   

                            stack.pop();
                            stackCount--;
                            alert("same Tags, so popped out from the stack" + stack);
                            }

                        else
                        {
                        stack.push(array[k]);
                        stackCount++;
                        alert("Pushed in to the stack as items compared are different");
                        }
                        }



        }
```

Ive posted my answer...I tried and this is where I am... any feedbacks or improvemnts from your side??? I m concerned about the part, , since it is a closed tag, it should pop out.. right??